# Google Apps Script "TypeError" when Parsing JSON to Google Sheets

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, typeerror

After two eight-hour days of Googling and trying various bits of code, I'm here, asking for your help.

Can anyone please help me understand what this error means?

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')`

Below is the Google Apps Script I'm running which never returns any data to my Google Sheet, only the TypeError above.

My end goal is so extremely simple: I need to take the data returned by the API and simply parse it into cells in a Google Sheet. I'm certain that the API is responsive as I've been able to see a "200" code (which indicates success) in the log as well as seeing the actual data I need to parse in its raw format in the log (when I rewrite the code to show the data in the log). The most I can tell is that there is something wrong with the forEach loop.

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = "https://example.com";
  var params = {
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(Username + ':' + Password),
      "Act-Database-Name": "Sample"
    }
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  var code = response.getResponseCode();
  var token = response.getContentText();

  Logger.log(code);
  Logger.log(token);

  var params2 = {
    "headers": { "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + token }
  };
  
  try {
    // call the API
    var url2 = "https://example.com/api/opportunities";
    var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, params2);

    var code2 = jsondata.getResponseCode();
    Logger.log(code2);

    var data = jsondata.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(data);

    // get data array
    var arrayData = json['opportunities']; // replace 'data' with the name of your 1st-level array

    // blank array to hold the data for Sheet
    var arrayProperties = [];

    // Add the arrayProperties to the array
    arrayData.forEach(function (el) {

      arrayProperties.push([el.status,
      el.opportunityName,
      el.contact,
      el.probabilityofClose,
      el.weightedTotal,
      el.total,
      el.editDate,
      el.estimatedCloseDate,
      el.actualCloseDate,
      el.recordManager,
      el.leadTime,
      el.accessLevel,
      el.associatedWith,
      el.company,
      el.competitor,
      el.createDate,
      el.daysinStage,
      el.daysOpen,
      el.grossMargin,
      el.importDate,
      el.lastEditedBy,
      el.openDate,
      el.opportunityField2,
      el.opportunityField3,
      el.opportunityField4,
      el.opportunityField5,
      el.opportunityField6,
      el.opportunityField7,
      el.opportunityField8,
      el.private,
      el.process,
      el.product,
      el.reason,
      el.recordCreator,
      el.referredBy,
      el.sourceid,
      el.stage,
      el.stageStartDate]
      );

    });


    // select the output sheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Current');        // replace 'Sheet1' with the name of your Sheet

    // calculate the number of rows and columns needed
    var numRows = arrayProperties.length;
    var numCols = arrayProperties[0].length;

    // output the numbers to the sheet
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, numRows, numCols).setValues(arrayProperties.reverse())


  }
  catch (error) {
    // deal with any errors
    Logger.log(error);
  };
}
```

According to the API documentation, the data should look like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "name": "string",
    "actualCloseDate": "2022-12-07T18:10:03.367Z",
    "companies": [
      {
        "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "name": "string"
      }
    ],
    "competitor": "string",
    "contactNames": "string",
    "contacts": [
      {
        "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "displayName": "string",
        "company": "string"
      }
    ],
    "creator": "string",
    "daysOpen": 0,
    "daysInStage": 0,
    "estimatedCloseDate": "2022-12-07T18:10:03.367Z",
    "stageStartDate": "2022-12-07T18:10:03.367Z",
    "grossMargin": 0,
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "name": "string"
      }
    ],
    "isPrivate": true,
    "manager": "string",
    "openDate": "2022-12-07T18:10:03.367Z",
    "probability": 0,
    "productTotal": 0,
    "reason": "string",
    "source": "string",
    "sourceId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "stage": {
      "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "name": "string",
      "description": "string",
      "probability": 0,
      "number": 0,
      "process": {
        "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "name": "string",
        "description": "string",
        "status": "None",
        "stagesCount": 0,
        "stages": [
          {}
        ]
      }
    },
    "status": "Open",
    "importDate": "2022-12-07T18:10:03.367Z",
    "totalPerCompany": 0,
    "totalPerContact": 0,
    "totalPerGroup": 0,
    "weightedTotal": 0,
    "quickbooksInvoiceId": "string",
    "relatedEntitiesResolver": true,
    "recordManagerID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "customFields": {},
    "created": "2022-12-07T18:10:03.367Z",
    "edited": "2022-12-07T18:10:03.367Z",
    "editedBy": "string",
    "recordOwner": "string",
    "recordManager": "string"
  }
]
```

The API documentation also shows a "Model" that looks like this:

```
Inline Model [
act.web.api.models.Opportunities.Opportunity
]
act.web.api.models.Opportunities.Opportunity {
id (string, optional): A unique identifier that represents a potential piece of business. ,
name (string, optional): The name of an opportunity. ,
actualCloseDate (string, optional): The date that the opportunity as closed. ,
companies (Array[act.web.api.models.Companies.EmbeddedCompany], optional): List of companies that are associated to this opportunity entity. ,
competitor (string, optional): Gets the name of the competitor for this opportunity. ,
contactNames (string, optional): The names of the contacts associated with this opportunity. ,
contacts (Array[act.web.api.models.Contacts.EmbeddedContact], optional): List of contacts that are associated to this opportunity entity. ,
creator (string, optional): The name of the creator of this opportunity. ,
daysOpen (integer, optional): The number of days this opportunity has been opened. ,
daysInStage (integer, optional): the number of days this opportunity has been in a given stage. ,
estimatedCloseDate (string, optional): The date the opportunity is expected to be closed. ,
stageStartDate (string, optional): The date the opportunity stage started. ,
grossMargin (number, optional): Represents the net sales less the cost of goods and services sold. ,
groups (Array[act.web.api.models.Groups.EmbeddedGroup], optional): List of groups that are associated to this opportunity entity. ,
isPrivate (boolean, optional): Indicates whether this opportunity is private ,
manager (string, optional): The name of the record manager of this opportunity. ,
openDate (string, optional): The date the opportunity was opened. ,
probability (integer, optional): The likelihood this opportunity will will be won by the close date. ,
productTotal (number, optional): The total cost of the product or services. ,
reason (string, optional): Describes why the opportunity status changed. ,
source (string, optional): Describes the source of the opportunity. ,
sourceId (string, optional): The external source id for the opportunity ,
stage (act.web.api.models.Opportunities.Stage, optional): The stage of the opportunity. ,
status (string, optional): This displays the status of the opportunity (Open, Won, Lost, or inactive). = ['Open', 'Won', 'Lost', 'Inactive'],
importDate (string, optional): This readonly property displays the date that the opportunity was imported into the system. ,
totalPerCompany (number, optional): The average total per associated company. ,
totalPerContact (number, optional): The average total per associated contact. ,
totalPerGroup (number, optional): The average total per associated group. ,
weightedTotal (number, optional): The weight of the product. ,
quickbooksInvoiceId (string, optional): Quickbooks external Id to match record with quickbooks contact ,
relatedEntitiesResolver (boolean, optional): If true: prevents related entities from serializing. ,
recordManagerID (string, optional): The record manager. ,
customFields (object, optional),
created (string, optional),
edited (string, optional),
editedBy (string, optional),
recordOwner (string, optional),
recordManager (string, optional)
}
act.web.api.models.Companies.EmbeddedCompany {
id (string, optional): Gets a unique identifier (id) for a given company. ,
name (string, optional): Gets the name of the company.
}
act.web.api.models.Contacts.EmbeddedContact {
id (string, optional): ,
displayName (string, optional, read only): ,
company (string, optional):
}
act.web.api.models.Groups.EmbeddedGroup {
id (string, optional): Gets a unique identifier (id) for a given group. ,
name (string, optional): Gets the name of the group.
}
act.web.api.models.Opportunities.Stage {
id (string, optional): Gets the unique identifier of the stage. ,
name (string, optional): Gets/Sets the name of the stage. ,
description (string, optional): Gets/Sets the description of the stage. ,
probability (integer, optional): Gets/Sets the probability of the stage. ,
number (integer, optional): The order of the stage progresses throw the process lifecycle. ,
process (act.web.api.models.Opportunities.Process, optional): Represents the current process for a given opportunity
}
act.web.api.models.Opportunities.Process {
id (string, optional): Gets the unique identifier of the process. ,
name (string, optional): The name of the process. ,
description (string, optional): The description of the process. ,
status (string, optional): The description of the process. = ['None', 'Active', 'Inactive'],
stagesCount (integer, optional): Count of stages of current process ,
stages (Array[act.web.api.models.Opportunities.Stage], optional): Customized stages for the new process
}
```

Thank you very much in advance ❤️.

Comment: Hello! I guess it would help folks get to the solution by providing here a sample of the data (replace sensitive values, of course), but in the format it comes in.

Comment: You left out the most important thing to be able to answer your question

Comment: Is property `opportunities` an array?

Comment: Thank you for your comments @onit and @Cooper. I have updated the question with more data from the API documentation. @Cooper: I chose ```opportunities``` as the value not quite understanding what I was supposed to enter. The full API documentation that I can access is here: https://actforweb.actops.com/act.web.api/Swagger/index.html#

Comment: Can you add the sample value of `jsondata.getContentText()`?